# Apache Commons Exec: анализ и вывод лога

Tags: apache, java, exec

Нужно запустить java программу и прочитать её лог. Apache Commons Exec выводит лог в NetBeans и выделяет его красным цветом. Как получить именно то, что выделено красным, без символов ">", чтобы потом вывести лог в JTextPane?
Вот код:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    try {
        initComponents();

        Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
        String fileSep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String javaPath = new File(System.getProperty("java.home")).getParentFile().toString() + fileSep + "bin" + fileSep + "java.exe";
        String myJarPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        if (!System.getProperty("file.separator").equals(myJarPath.substring(myJarPath.length() - 1))) {
            myJarPath += System.getProperty("file.separator");
        }
        myJarPath += "craftbukkit.jar";
        jLabel1.setText(myJarPath);
        File jar = new File(myJarPath);
        if (!jar.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File founded!");
        }

        CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("\"" + javaPath + "\" -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar \"" + myJarPath + "\"");
        System.out.println("Запуск команды: " + cl + "\nЛог программы:\n");

        int exitvalue = exec.execute(cl);
    } catch (ExecuteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

А вот скриншот:

[image]

Мне нужно вывести в JTextPane то, что в нижней части скриншота написано красным цветом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно задать кастомный обработчик для **Executor**

```
    PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(output, System.err);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
```

Comment: С выводом лога вроде разобрался, спасибо! А как отправить команду в запущенную консольную программу?